# jQuery .combobox() set autofocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, autocomplete

jQuery has .focus method(), In autocomplete I just set focus with "autofocus : true", like this :

```
$('#AutoCompleteId').autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true
    });
```

however I'm using .combobox() jQuery, not autocomplete, how can I set auto focus in .combobox() jQuery?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you using this? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox
If so, autoFocus should still work.

Comment: yes, I'm using that, autoFocus should still work ? I don't know the script to set autofocus :( can you explain the code to me?.

Comment: The code snippet you have provided is insufficient. Please provide the rest.

Comment: now my code just like this, $('#AutoCompleteId').combobox();